# SQL: Display joined data on a day to day basis anchored on a start date

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Perhaps my title is misleading, but I am not sure how else to phrase this. I have two tables, tblL and tblDumpER. They are joined based on the field SubjectNumber. This is a one (tblL) to many (tblDumpER) relationship.

I need to write a query that will give me, for all my subjects, a value from tblDumpER associated with a date in tblL. This is to say:

```
SELECT tblL.SubjectNumber, tblDumpER.ER_Q1
FROM tblL
LEFT JOIN tblDumpER ON tblL.SubjectNumber=tblDumpER.SubjectNumber
WHERE tblL.RandDate=tblDumpER.ER_DATE And tblDumpER.ER_Q1 Is Not Null
```

This is straightforward enough. My problem is the value RandDate from tblL is different for every subject. However, it needs to be displayed as Day1 so I can have tblDumpER.ER_Q1 as Day1 for every subject. Then I need RandDate+1 As Day2, etc until I hit either null or Day84. The 'dumb' solution is to write 84 queries. This is obviously not practical. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I appreciate the responses so far but I don't think that I'm explaining this correctly so here is some example data:

SubjectNumber RandDate

1001             1/1/2013 
1002             1/8/2013 
 
1003             1/15/2013

SubjectNumber    ER_DATE      ER_Q1

1001             1/1/2013      5 
1001             1/2/2013      6 
1001             1/3/2013      2 
1002             1/8/2013      1 
1002             1/9/2013      10 
1002             1/10/2013     8 
1003             1/15/2013     7 
1003             1/16/2013     4 
1003             1/17/2013     3

Desired outcome:
(Where Day1=RandDate, Day2=RandDate+1, Day3=RandDate+2)

SubjectNumber Day1_ER_Q1      Day2_ER_Q1       Day3_ER_Q1

1001              5                6                2 
1002              1                10               8 
1003              7                4                3

This data is then going to be plotted on a graph with Day# on the X-axis and ER_Q1 on the Y-axis

Comment: Please tag post with version of SQL you are using. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps:

- Create a query that gets the MIN date for each SubjectNumber
- Join this query to your existing query, so you can perform a DATEDIFF calculation on the MIN date and the date of the current record.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what it is that you need, but perhaps a calendar table would be of help.  Just create a local table that contains all of the days of the year in it, then use that table to JOIN your dates up?